# ReactJS TypeError: l.replaceRule is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am compiling a project with npm which was working perfectly fine a day before and now has suddenly stopped working for the code without changing anything. Error I am getting in the browser is attached for reference.

[image: Error coming in browser]

Steps I am following to clean compile my project:

```
rm -rf package-lock.json 
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf build/  
npm install 
npm run build
```

My package.json file contains following data:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Dashboard",
  "author": "Inc.",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/core": "1.3.13",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/docs": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/system": "4.9.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.4.0",
    "@sentry/react": "5.30.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "6.0.4",
    "@types/dragula": "3.7.0",
    "@types/google-map-react": "1.1.8",
    "@types/react": "16.9.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
    "@types/react-helmet": "5.0.16",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.5",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "11.0.4",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.2",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "css-vendor": "2.0.8",
    "date-fns": "2.15.0",
    "google-map-react": "1.1.7",
    "immer": "9.0.3",
    "json-logic-js": "2.0.1",
    "jss": "10.4.0",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "2.5.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "polished": "3.6.5",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "1.0.6",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.10.0",
    "react-date-range": "1.1.3",
    "react-datetime": "3.0.4",
    "react-diff-viewer": "3.1.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-dragula": "1.1.17",
    "react-feather": "2.0.8",
    "react-google-login": "5.1.23",
    "react-helmet": "5.2.1",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.16",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.8",
    "react-quill": "1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "7.2.1",
    "react-router": "5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "13.5.0",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "styled-components": "5.1.1",
    "typescript": "3.9.7",
    "universal-cookie": "4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/json-logic-js": "1.2.1",
    "@types/react-date-range": "1.1.4",
    "source-map-explorer": "2.5.2"
  }
}
```

Let me know what would have changed suddenly that same code no longer works.

More details:

```
$ npm -v
8.0.0
```

```
$ node -v
v16.11.1
```

Edit 1:

instrument.ts line 129
Function.prototype.apply.call(originalConsoleLevel, global.console, args);

[image: line 129 instrument.ts]

Comment: What is in the `instrument.ts` file in 129 line?

Comment: Edited the post with error in instrument.ts file

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue was with "jss": "10.4.0" in the package.json file. Material UI also has dependency and was adding "jss": "^10.0.3". I guess may be due to conflict it was causing replaceRule function issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you run on your project

```
npm ls jss
```

it it will list all the packages that use jss
[npm ls result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymBq7.png)

As you can see I use for jss 10.5.1 while material-ui/styles uses 10.8.0
all I had to do is upgrade the version of the jss to match the version that mui/styles use

```
npm install jss@10.8.0
```

that made it work, also I would recommend seeing in the project where you actually use jss and see if you can avoid it

Comment: This is not an answer